# php mysql affected_rows showing 2

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

I am having a bit of trouble. This was working until I added a second database class to run some test methods. After removing this I am now getting this error and can't understand why.

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/bitandpi/public_html/temp/build/build.php on line 49

Here is my code:

```
$urltag = urldecode($contentPageVar);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM shopproducts 
           WHERE urltag = '$urltag' AND urltag != ''
           AND pd_active > 0 AND pd_visible > 0";

$result             = $database->fetch_array($sql);

echo $database->affected_row()."<BR>";
print_r($result);
exit;

if($database->affected_row() > 0) {
    // run code
}
```

I have printed the $sql var and ran it straight into phpmyadmin query and it returns 0 results.

However if I run the above code it prints the following on my screen:

```
2
Array ( )
```

Why is it telling me it is affecting rows when it is not?

Thanks

Comment: where is line number 49 ?

Comment: Have you used any where UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT statement?

Comment: `affected_row()` will work only for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Comment: Line 49 was the // run code line. It had extract($result[0]); I have typed $database = new Database; at the top of build.php and it worked. There must be another instance started somewhere, which has confused me. Time to search. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To found number of fetched record please use count(*) in select statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have use **num_rows**.

```
$urltag = urldecode($contentPageVar);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM shopproducts WHERE urltag = '$urltag' AND urltag != '' AND pd_active > 0 AND pd_visible > 0";

$result = $database->query($sql);

echo $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
echo "<br/>";

if($row_cnt>0){
     // run code
   $result1             = $database->fetch_array($sql);
}
```